# Can we make Multiple Objects Display to "Bounds (in Context)" in one Click?

Tags: 3d-view

Trying to display multiple Linked objects to Bounds (Context Properties) in one click, can we do that in Blender 2.8?
Currently, we have to do it one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58771/transforming-multiple-objects-to-have-equal-dimensions/58773#58773 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/bevel-and-resolution-multiple-selected-curves/104470#104470 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/how-to-unset-multiple-values-from-bezier-objects/87237#87237

Comment: This is the way :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/display-bounding-box-around-objects